# With PIL, how can I represent a string with bits to a b/w image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm experimenting with PIL and generating images from a string to be specific.

I have this code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import array
from PIL import Image

photo_data = "35c1f6ebc3ef2d424ced351b65be8c396f8396d69411d7e7185f2a5e9eaab7da"

scale = 16  ## equals to hexadecimal
num_of_bits = 8
allbits = []
for i in range(len(photo_data)):
    photobits = bin(int(photo_data[i], scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)
    allbits.append(photobits)

photo_image = Image.frombytes("1", (8, 64), "".join(allbits).replace("1","F"), "raw")

photo_image.show()
```

There are no errors in this code but the image I see, does not look right to me.

[image]

I would expect the top line to be '00000011' but it is '11001111'

It is probably something with the parameters of the frombytes function. But what? :D

Actually what I'm trying to do is to represent each character in the `photo_data` string as one line in an image with each enabled bit colored black.

Maybe I'm going in the wrong direction and there is a much easier way?

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now is a series of rows that represents the binary visualization of the ASCII characters "0" and "F", because that's what your list contains. "0" is 00110000 and "F" is 01000110. These match up with your rows, white being a 1 bit and black being a 0 bit.

Right now you're trying to represent each pixel with a single byte-sized character. But `frombytes` actually expects one pixel per bit, meaning a single character represents eight pixels. So what you should be doing is populating the array with characters whose ordinal value is equal to the values of your photo data string. So for example "d" should translate not to "13" or "00001101", but rather the thirteenth ASCII character, "\r". You can perform this translation fairly easily by converting to int, then converting back to string with `chr`.

```
import struct
from PIL import Image

s = "35c1f6ebc3ef2d424ced351b65be8c396f8396d69411d7e7185f2a5e9eaab7da"
bits = [chr(int(c,16)) for c in s]
photo_image = Image.frombytes("1", (8, 64), "".join(bits), "raw")
photo_image.show()
```

Result:

[image]

If you would prefer white and black to correspond to 1 and 0 instead of vice versa, you can invert the integer value by XORing it with b11111111.

```
bits = [chr(0xFF ^ int(c,16)) for c in s]
```

Result:

[image]